# what is the use of params field in angular routing?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

What is the use of params in state routing?

```
.state("app.home",{
   url:"/Home",
   params:{
    },
   templateUrl:"/.../..html",
   controller: HomeCtrl,
   controllerAs: vm
})
```

Comment: Assuming you are using AngularJS and angular-ui-router, this is my answer: you define available stateParams. Means, all parameters passed to the URL or to $state.go(state, null, params) which will be processed and available in $stateParams service.
See the Docs for more info: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#params